# Passing array values to laravel factory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, factory, faker

I'm trying to create a fake data seeder using `fzaninotto/faker` and `factory` in Laravel 5.4. I want to send an array of data to the factory, in which i can pick a random element using faker. The array is a result of a DB query, which I don't want to do recursively in the Modelfactory. Here is what I done.

In seeder, it calls the factory.

```
factory(App\Models\Types::class, 10)->create();
```

In Modelfactory, the function is as below

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Types::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $materials = App\Models\Material::pluck('id')->all();
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->word,
        'material_id' => $faker->randomElement($materials),
        'status' => 1,
        'display_status' => 1,
    ];
});
```

The array `$materials` is created with the model call to `Material` is done in each loop, which I want to avoid. It takes too much time to seed more data (say 100000). Is there any option pass the data from seeder file to factory? Moving the Model call before the factory definition will now solve my issue because the Material is seeded in some other seeder file, which results empty array because the `Modelfactory` is loaded at the beginning by default.

Answer (score 3):

I personally consider factories as just a way to fill [fillable attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) of a model. I take care of the relationships in the seeders.

Let's say you have two models `Type` and `Material`. You create two factories named `TypeFactory` and `MaterialFactory`. For instance `TypeFactory` would be as follows:

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Types::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'display_status' => 1,
        'name' => $faker->unique()->word,
        'status' => 1
    ];
});
```

Then in the seeder of the `types` table, you could do:

```
$materials = factory(App\Models\Material::class, 10)->create();

$types = factory(App\Models\Type::class, 100)->make();

$types->each(function($type) use ($materials) {
    $material = $materials->random();

    $type->material()->associate($material);
    $type->save();
});
```

Note the difference between `create()` and `make()`. `create()` persists the model and `make()` only returns an instance of it.

This is probably not related to your problem but `App\Models\Material::pluck('id')->all()` is not correct. You should first retrieve all instances of the model and then call the `pluck` method:

```
$materialsIds = App\Models\Material::all()->pluck('id');
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: No it's not. Because, materials are seeded using DatabaseSeeder and Types are seeder using DummySeeder file. So I can't club those to a single file.

Comment: You know you can import other seeder files into DatabaseSeeder.php. Inside the `run()` method just do `$this->call(DummySeeder::class);`.

Comment: `DummySeeder` is optional. I can't include that in `DatabaseSeeder`.

Answer (score 2):

Define materials above private function, and 'use' it:

```
$materials = App\Models\Material::pluck('id')->all();
$factory->define(App\Models\Types::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) use ($materials)
{
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->word,
        'material_id' => $faker->randomElement($materials),
        'status' => 1,
        'display_status' => 1,
    ];
});
```

Comment: That won't work because the material data is just another seeder which will be executed just before type seeder. Since the whole Medelfactory is loaded with laravel the query result will be empty array. I've mentioned that in the question already.

Comment: Ah, allright. Then why not simply create a query that returns a random id?

Comment: Still I have to make a db query on each request. That's what it makes the seeding slow.